# Not sure how to perform ZOH upsampling

Tags: sampling, zoh

Sorry if the question looks pretty naive. My goal is to up-sample a given signal x[n] by a factor of M using the zero order hold interpolation function.

[image]

The basic idea of up-sampling is to add M-1 zeros after each sample. So that makes sense. That forms MN new samples, where N is the length of the sampled signal x[n]. Now if I want to apply ZOH should I go and hold each sample value for one sample interval? Say if M=2 the above discrete signal would have become like this after applying ZOH:

[image]

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: no, for a regular ZOH, there should be no zeros inserted.  only hold $x[n]$ constant until $x[n+1]$ comes along.

Comment: Yes, right, I was wrong. There shouldn't be any zeros inserted. That's the convolution of the signal x[n] with the rect impulse response that forms the reconstructed signal at the output.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. There is a trick you can use to code this process very easily. Assuming Matlab syntax, define a rectangular impulse response with `M` ones:

```
ir = ones(1,M);
```

Then, filter the upsampled train of impulses `x`:

```
zoh = conv(x,ir);
```

and you're done!

Comment: Seems cool. But what if I want to apply an FOH interpolation what ir should be then?

Comment: by *"FOH"*, do you mean linear interpolation, right?

Comment: Yeah, actually. I think the triangular impulse response can do it, but not sure how to modify ir